# AVCaptureDevice depreciated to AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession use front camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Can't find an up-to-date answer on this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

AVCaptureDevice *device = [self frontCamera];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
[session addInput:input];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_logo];
[session startRunning];
}

- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontCamera {
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The `NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];` is depreciated and is asking to use `AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession`. How can I correctly implement AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession to this code?
I would just like to use the front camera.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get front camera, back camera and audio with AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894630/how-to-get-front-camera-back-camera-and-audio-with-avcapturedevicediscoverysess)

Answer (score 0):

You can access front camera by code blow.

```
- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontCamera {
    NSArray *devices;
    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
        AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *session = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTrueDepthCamera, AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera] mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo position:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
        devices = session.devices;
    }else{
        devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevicediscoverysession):

`AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession` can find available capture devices currently as also as monitor availability of specified device.
`AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera` specify normal front camera.
`AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTrueDepthCamera` specify depth front camera base infrared, which only available on iPhone X.

Comment: Please note that `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTrueDepthCamera` your answer mentions is only available on iOS 11.1 or newer.

Comment: In the given code, You are creating AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession object using AVCaptureDevicePositionFront parameter , then no need to iterate it again.