# IOS devicesWithMediaType deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently using the method:

`NSArray *captureDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];`

to get a list of devices but XCode is giving me a warning:

`Use AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession instead`

I have looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.discoverysession) but do not know how to access the devices array

```
AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *session = [[AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession alloc]init];
???
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Create [`AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevicediscoverysession?language=objc) for your requirement and then call `devices` method to get `Array` of currently available devices matching the session’s criteria

Code:

```
AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *captureDeviceDiscoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera] 
                                      mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                       position:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
NSArray *captureDevices = [captureDeviceDiscoverySession devices];
```

#### Swift 4+

```
let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)
```

> Available
>
> [Device types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype)
>
> [Media types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediatype)
>
> [Position](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/position)

Comment: Swift 4: 
`let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)`

Comment: Use AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified for the position to search for devices regardless of position.

Answer (score 2):

```
AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front)
```

I think something like that would work. I think the AVCapture.DiscoverySession's initializer may be helpful as well. 
See the documentation and the stack overflow post on something similar in swift. Let me know if it helped!:)

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice
- [How to get front camera, back camera and audio with AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894630/how-to-get-front-camera-back-camera-and-audio-with-avcapturedevicediscoverysess)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.discoverysession/2361539-init

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers, here are my two cents on this issue.

Deprecated code:

```
let availableCameraDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video)
```

Swift 5:

```
let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
        deviceTypes: [ .builtInWideAngleCamera ],
        mediaType: .video,
        position: .unspecified
    )
let availableCameraDevices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices
```