# devicesWithMediaType is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated

I have the following code:

```
NSArray * devices = [ AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo ];

// 2. Iterate through the device array and if a device is a camera, check if it's the one we want:
for ( AVCaptureDevice * device in devices )
{
    if ( useFrontCamera && AVCaptureDevicePositionFront == [ device position ] )
    {
        // We asked for the front camera and got the front camera, now keep a pointer to it:
        m_camera = device;
    }
    else if ( !useFrontCamera && AVCaptureDevicePositionBack == [ device position ] )
    {
        // We asked for the back camera and here it is:
        m_camera = device;
    }
}
```

the warning says that `devicesWithMediaType` is deprecated and I should use `AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession` instead, I have tried the following:

```
AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *captureDeviceDiscoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera] 
                                      mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                       position:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
NSArray *captureDevices = [captureDeviceDiscoverySession devices];
```

but the array of devices has only my back camera and not my front cam, any help?

Comment: *but the array of devices has only my back camera and not my front cam* - that's to be expected when you initialize `AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession` with `AVCaptureDevicePositionBack`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOS devicesWithMediaType deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735554/ios-deviceswithmediatype-deprecated)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevicediscoverysession/2361539-discoverysessionwithdevicetypes?language=objc)

> Pass AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified  to search for devices
>   regardless of position.

So use AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified to find all capture devices.

So the code will look like this:

```
AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *captureDeviceDiscoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera] 
                                      mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                       position: AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified]; // here you pass AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified to find all capture devices

NSArray *captureDevices = [captureDeviceDiscoverySession devices];
```